# How to logout from Facebook using an activity

Tags: android, facebook

I'm making an Android app using the Facebook SDK ..and the example the app is based on uses a fragment to log in and out. I'd like to be able to log out of an activity and I'm therefore assuming I'll need to call the Facebook logout fragment...What's the best way to do it?

Comment: show us your code or example code

Comment: I don't think code is relevant here...cause the query is generalised to just logging out of any activity using the Facebook SDK 3.0...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To logout of facebook, you just need to call

```
try {
            facebook.logout(this);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

**EDIT:**

for Facebook sdk 3.0, use below method:

```
if (Session.getActiveSession() != null) {
Session.getActiveSession().closeAndClearTokenInformation();
}
Session.setActiveSession(null);
```

Just make sure to clear your user session token however you are storing it. You may refer to this [link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/3.0/Session#closeAndClearTokenInformation%28%29).

Comment: Wasn't the Facebook class deprecated?

Comment: Yeah..thanks alot :-) Jesus they went and complicated everything.